# WPF MediaElement, change audio track

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I'm writing a Media Player using WPF and the MediaElement.
I was playing a video i have that has several audio tracks. But they are both playing at the same time :(

How do i just play one of them ? is it at all possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem is in the audio and video DirectShow codecs you use. Can you play the video correct in the Windows Media Player? If no, please re-install the appropriated codecs.

Some months ago I have completely prototyped the requirements to switch audio tracks in order to show the video-help in our multi-language software.
My experience shows some alternatives:

- Use the WMP-control via WinForms host, and then change the language like:

  var control = ((IWMPControls3)wmpControl.Ctlcontrols);
  control.currentAudioLanguage = 9; // english

The Complete list of the LCID you can find [here](http://www.livio.net/main/charset.asp).
To list all audio tracks in the video you can use something like:

```
wmpControl.PlayStateChange += (o, args) => {
  if(args.newState == 3) {
    var control = ((IWMPControls3)wmpControl.Ctlcontrols);
    for(int i = 1; i <= control.audioLanguageCount; i++) {
      MessageBox.Show(control.getAudioLanguageID(i) + ": " + control.getAudioLanguageDescription(i));
    }
  }
};
```

- Use the separate audio tracks and play it synchronously to the video using the [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx). The main problem of this method is, that you must synchronize audio and video playback, start, stop, seeking,.. manually.

I hope this helps you to choose your solution.

Comment: Thank you! This has saved me a lot of time! I work on the video help  in wpf now, so I will try to use a windows media player control.

Comment: I had the same problem that both audio tracks played at the same time. Reinstalling the K-Lite Codec Pack solved my problem. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the WPF MediaElement.  If you have some DirectShow know-how, you can try my [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) and either modify the MediaUriElement/Player or create your own.

Comment: I came across this post and am trying to do the same thing. I am using the MediaKit but I am not sure how I would go about modifying it to switch audio streams. Any elaboration on this would be greatly appreciated.